# Why does amsrefs do a pagebreak after the header?

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, amsbook, amsrefs

I am using the document class amsbook and generate the amsrefs bibliography by

```
\begin{bibdiv}
  \begin{biblist}
    \include{bibcode}
  \end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
```

Now, there is a page that *only* says **Bibliography**, and the first actual reference appears on the next page.

I have no idea how this problem occurs. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example. Just posting sniplets like this, makes it less likely to get help from others. Not everyone has experience with `amsrefs`

Comment: @daleif: Okay -- on the way.

Comment: (no longer necessary as Andrew Swann's answer solves the problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `\input` not `\include`.  The latter adds a `\clearpage`.  Here is the first example from the AMS documentation in your set-up:

[image: Sample output]

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}
Alan Sokal~\cite{Sokal96} recommends Bourbaki’s text~\cite{Bourbaki70}
for a gentle introduction to set theory. 

\begin{bibdiv} 
\begin{biblist}
\input{bibcode}
\end{biblist} 
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

with `bibcode.tex` containing:

```
\bib{Bourbaki70}{book}{
title={Th\'eorie des ensembles},
author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},
date={1970},
publisher={Hermann},
address={Paris}
}

\bib{Sokal96}{article}{
title={Trangressing the boundaries},
subtitle={Toward a transformative hermeneutics of quantum gravity},
author={Sokal, Alan},
journal={Social Text},
volume={46/47},
date={1996}, 
pages={217--252}
}
```